# Axis labels on invisible axes in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

Is it possible to have a visible axis label on an invisble axis? I would like to plot 2 axes that have, apart from their own ylabels, also a common one:

```
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.pyplot import *

figure()

ax1 = axes([0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2]); ylabel("Label 1")
ax2 = axes([0.3, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2]); ylabel("Label 2")

ax_common = axes([0.2, 0.2, 0.5, 0.5], zorder=-10)
xticks([]); yticks([])
ylabel("Common", fontsize="x-large")

savefig("out.png")
```

The code above produces this plot:

[out.png](http://picpaste.com/out-FilQvUeE.png)

Is there a way to remove axis lines? If I add `ax_common.set_axis_off()`, the axes and the ylabel is removed. Do I have to create a text label instead, without create the additional axes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
ax_common.set_frame_on(False)
```